# Фильтрация строки, (убрать лишние символы)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, текст

Есть некие строки, например:

1. antonio vivaldi - The Four Seasons
2. antonio+vivaldi The_Four_Seasons
3. "*antonio_vivaldi** "THE FOUR SEASONS"

Возможно ли написать регулярное выражение которое буде фильтровать строки, чтобы конечный результат был таким: Antonio Vivaldi - The Four Seasons

Comment: Судя по `был таким: Antonio Vivaldi - The Four Seasons` еще и первую букву в каждом слове хотите заглавную, а остальные строчные?

Comment: Да, то есть чтобы красиво выглядело, если записали: вася пупкин - (ДИРЕКТОР), то чтобы вывело: Вася Пупкин - Директор. (Если такое возможно конечно)

Comment: Начните, вот с такого /(\w+)/ - https://www.regex101.com/r/rP8iG6/1. Можно вызвать preg_replace_callback и в функции сделать правильный регистр каждому найденному слову

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Набросал на скорую руку.

```
$strings = [
    'antonio vivaldi - The Four Seasons',
    'antonio+vivaldi The_Four_Seasons',
    '"*antonio_vivaldi** "THE FOUR SEASONS"'
];

foreach($strings as $string) {
    $words = [];
    preg_match_all('/\w+/', $string, $words);

    $cleanWords = [];
    foreach($words as $word) {
        $cleanWords[] = preg_replace('/[+_]/', " ", $word);
    }

    $cleanString = implode(' ', $cleanWords[0]);
}

?>
```

Comment: Он выводит: antonio vivaldi THE FOUR SEASONS

Comment: Если вы про отсутствие дефиса, то можно изменить регулярку на `preg_match_all('/[\w-]+/', $string, $words);`. А вот с добавлением дефиса сложнее. Если строки всегда с разным форматированием его не добавить, так как не определить куда его надо запихивать.

Comment: Я о том что отображается в разных регистрах... А хотелось бы так: Antonio Vivaldi - The Four Seasons

Comment: Добавьте методы `strtolower` и `ucfirst`.

Comment: А вы до сих пор работаете в кодировке `win-1251`? :)

Comment: Нет, я не из fl.ru ;)